# How can we get unique elements from any ORDER BY DECREASING OR INCREASING

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, unique

Code given below is taken from the stackoverflow.com !!! Can anyone tell me how to get the array elements order by decreaseing or increasing !! plz help me !!! Thanks in advance

```
$contents = file_get_contents($htmlurl);

// Get rid of style, script etc
$search = array('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',  // Strip out javascript
           '@<head>.*?</head>@siU',            // Lose the head section
           '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
           '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments including CDATA
);

$contents = preg_replace($search, '', $contents); 

$result = array_count_values(
              str_word_count(
                  strip_tags($contents), 1
                  )
              );

print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need PHP's [sort](http://php.net/sort) function. I won't duplicate the manual here.

Answer (score 0):

After stripping the tags, you get an array of words used in the string by using `str_word_count` next you are using `array_count_values` to get the frequency of the words.

Now to sort the words based on frequency you can use `asort` for ascending order or `arsort` for descending order.

```
$result = array_count_values(
              str_word_count(
                  strip_tags($contents), 1
                  ));
asort($result);  // Add this.
```

[See it](http://www.ideone.com/C2PZl)